# How can I turn off the processing indicator after the return from ssrs report in mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a button on my site that runs a SQL Server Report Services report. It takes some time to run and I wanted to show a processing indicator to my users. This was easy enough. This is in a form that runs the action in the controller.

```html
<input 
  id="submitProcessingStandard" 
  type="submit" 
  class="btn btn-info" 
  value="PDF Report as of Date Below" 
  onclick="turnOn"
/>
```

This turns on the processing gif:

```js
function turnOn() {
  $("#processingStandard").show();
}
```

The action is very simple.

```js
public IActionResult PDF(CustomCrimesAndDistricts ccd) {
  return Redirect("http://xxxxxx/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDSP%2fDSP&rs:Format=PDF&enddate=" +
    ccd.EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat));
}
```

Once the file has been downloaded, is there any way to re-hide the processing gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get around this in a different way. I do a synchronous download in the controller and then I can return to the view with whatever I need. Thank for looking. I think this is probably the best way to do it. Any other ways will always be considered. Thanks for looking.